# Assigning total to correct month from date range

Tags: r, database, accounting

I've got a data set with reservation data that has the below format :

```
property   <- c('casa1', 'casa2', 'casa3')
check_in   <- as.Date(c('2018-01-01', '2018-01-30','2018-02-28'))
check_out  <- as.Date(c('2018-01-02', '2018-02-03', '2018-03-02'))
total_paid <- c(100,110,120)

df <- data.frame(property,check_in,check_out, total_paid)
```

My goal is to have the monthly `total_paid` amount divided by days and assigned to each month correctly for budget reasons.
While there's no issue for `casa1`, `casa2` and `casa3` have days reserved in both months and the totals get skewed because of this issue.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What is your expected output for the given example?

Comment: Hey Ronak, the output should be something like this:
January   <- 100 + 73.3
February  <- 36.7 + 60
March      <- 60
For me it's important to be able to assign the average per night from the by the month in which the actual night took place. Apologies for the poor example choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(id = seq_along(property), # make few variable to help
         day_paid = total_paid / as.numeric(check_out - check_in),
         date = check_in) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  complete(date = seq.Date(check_in, (check_out - 1), by = "day")) %>% # get date for each day of stay (except last)
  ungroup() %>% # make one row per day of stay
  mutate(month = cut(date, breaks = "month")) %>% # determine month of date
  fill(property, check_in, check_out, total_paid, day_paid) %>% 
  group_by(id, month) %>% 
  summarise(property = unique(property),
            check_in = unique(check_in),
            check_out = unique(check_out),
            total_paid = unique(total_paid),
            paid_month = sum(day_paid)) # summarise per month
```

result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Groups:   id [3]
     id month      property check_in   check_out  total_paid paid_month
  <int> <fct>      <fct>    <date>     <date>          <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1 2018-01-01 casa1    2018-01-01 2018-01-02        100        100
2     2 2018-01-01 casa2    2018-01-30 2018-02-03        110         55
3     2 2018-02-01 casa2    2018-01-30 2018-02-03        110         55
4     3 2018-02-01 casa3    2018-02-28 2018-03-02        120         60
5     3 2018-03-01 casa3    2018-02-28 2018-03-02        120         60
```

I hope it's somewhat readable but please ask if there is something I should explain. Convention is that people don't pay the last day of a stay, so I took that into account.

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed and it's very neat and readable. Big up for noticing what I didn't specify (the last day of a stay is not paid) too!